# How to modify key in a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, key

How can I change the value of a number of keys in a dictionary.

I have the following dictionary :

```
SortedDictionary<int,SortedDictionary<string,List<string>>>
```

I want to loop through this sorted dictionary and change the key to key+1 if the key value is greater than a certain amount.

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Comment: This question sounds like you are trying to manually insert an item and keep it sorted (specifically, making room for one). Note the SortedDictionary does this for you already.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As Jason said, you can't change the key of an existing dictionary entry. You'll have to remove/add using a new key like so:

```
// we need to cache the keys to update since we can't
// modify the collection during enumeration
var keysToUpdate = new List<int>();

foreach (var entry in dict)
{
    if (entry.Key < MinKeyValue)
    {
        keysToUpdate.Add(entry.Key);
    }
}

foreach (int keyToUpdate in keysToUpdate)
{
    SortedDictionary<string, List<string>> value = dict[keyToUpdate];

    int newKey = keyToUpdate + 1;

    // increment the key until arriving at one that doesn't already exist
    while (dict.ContainsKey(newKey))
    {
        newKey++;
    }

    dict.Remove(keyToUpdate);
    dict.Add(newKey, value);
}
```

Comment: I think you might encounter an OutOfBoundsException with keyToUpdate +1

Comment: @Roboto: You might get an `OverflowException` if `keyToUpdate == int.MaxValue`; other than that, though, I don't see how adding two integers is going to give an `OutOfBoundsException`...

Comment: @Roboto: Maybe you meant on adding the new key to the dictionary? In that case, no, the `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add` method doesn't throw an `OutOfBoundsException`, only `ArgumentNullException` and `ArgumentException`; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7620520y.aspx.

Answer (score 26):

You need to remove the items and re-add them with their new key. Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx):

> Keys must be immutable as long as they are used as keys in the `SortedDictionary(TKey, TValue)`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use LINQ statment for it

```
var maxValue = 10
sd= sd.ToDictionary(d => d.key > maxValue ? d.key : d.Key +1, d=> d.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind recreating the dictionary, you could use a LINQ statment.

```
var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, SortedDictionary<string, List<string>>>();
var insertAt = 10;
var newValues = dictionary.ToDictionary(
    x => x.Key < insertAt ? x.Key : x.Key + 1,
    x => x.Value);
return new SortedDictionary<int, SortedDictionary<string, List<string>>>(newValues);
```

or

```
var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, SortedDictionary<string, List<string>>>();
var insertAt = 10;
var newValues = dictionary.ToDictionary(
    x => x.Key < insertAt ? x.Key : x.Key + 1,
    x => x.Value);
dictionary.Clear();
foreach(var item in newValues) dictionary.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
```

Comment: No need to create a new to create a variable for it.
See my comment